# Autocomplete or Code Analyzer not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, autocomplete

I am currently working on recyclerview adapter. I can not work further because my autocomplete/code analyzer is apparently not working. I need it to generate the implementation of Recyclerview.Adapter automatically. please help me..

I have a hunch that the problem was caused by my gradle configuration. FYI, everything works fine before i resync my gradle (module). here is my current gradle configuration:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.toharifqi.myfavoritesports"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$constraint_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.3.5'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.3.5'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"

    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$recyclerview_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$room_version"

    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$retrofit_version"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$logging_interceptor_version"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$kotlin_coroutines_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "org.koin:koin-core:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android:$koin_version"
    implementation "org.koin:koin-android-viewmodel:$koin_version"
}
```

and this is my gradle configuration for project level:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = "1.4.10"

    ext.appcompat_version = "1.1.0"
    ext.core_ktx_version = "1.3.2"
    ext.constraint_version = "2.0.4"
    ext.legacy_support_version = "1.0.0"
    ext.junit_version = "4.13.1"
    ext.androidx_junit_version = "1.1.2"
    ext.espresso_version = "3.3.0"
    ext.multidex_version = "2.0.1"

    ext.cardview_version = "1.0.0"
    ext.recyclerview_version = "1.1.0"
    ext.material_version = "1.2.1"
    ext.glide_version = "4.12.0"

    ext.room_version = "2.2.5"

    ext.retrofit_version = "2.9.0"
    ext.logging_interceptor_version = '4.9.0'

    ext.kotlin_coroutines_version = "1.3.9"
    ext.lifecycle_version = "2.2.0"

    ext.koin_version = "2.1.6"


    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just found the problem, it was caused by my android core ktx version. previously it was implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'. After I changed to implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2' everything works fine. thank you